Spotfire- Comparing Depth Ranges After Table Pivot
I have a data table that looks like this: 
To clarify, an Item can complete a single section or multiple sections, depending on it's In and Out Depths.
I've already pivoted Table B into Table A due to having more rows than Table A (Table A is my main Table). The issue that I'm running into is how to add my calculated column called "Sections Completed" to Table A+B, without having to make multiple case statements to define the sections that an item completed. My question is- Is there a better way I could be doing this or is there a logical way to code this calculated column without having to do multiple case statements? My real table has many more section types and depths, so this could potentially be extremely time consuming. Thanks for the feedback!

what makes a section complete?

The Sections should have their own start and ending depths, but the table that stores them does not have an ending depth. So the section is the labeled section until the next section value occurs. I could add a calculated column that makes an ending depth equal to the next section depth, if that's helpful?

I should also note that the depths for these sections can fluctuate from location to location, but the names of the sections will remain the same always

Yes, it is not clear what the end depth of each section is. My initial thoughts, after this is clarified would be either: pivot A into B rather than B into A. Or create an iron python script.
